# changing video source using button html

Tags: javascript, html, button, video

i'm trying to change the video source at the click of a button. The aim is that the user can click the button (ie video title) and the video they want will appear. I'm struggling to get this code to work. Vid 1 appears but non of the buttons are functioning.

Does any one have any thought as to where i'm going wrong?
thanks

html

```
<button onClick="changevid('videos/vid1.mp4')">Video 1</button>
<button onClick="changevid('videos/vid2.mp4')">Video 2</button>
<button onClick="changevid('videos/vid3.mp4')">Video 3</button>

<video controls id="change">
  <source src="videos/Vid1.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
```

JS

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

function changevid(buttonLink) {

document.getElementById('change').src = buttonlink;

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to be careful about spelling/case-sensitivity. You have passed in buttonLink (with a capital L) and you are assigning that value to the `src`, but spelt with a lowercase l. These things do make a difference! (The same error has been made with vid1.mp4/Vid1.mp4)

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/w0gdct5v/) (linked to a video on my website - only the first video works). If you click Video 1 button, you will see the video update. However, if you change the uppercase to lowercase in the `buttonLink`, you will see that the code won't work.

Hope this helps

Comment: ah thank you for spotting this, it works now! not sure how i missed this

Answer (score 2):

Well i think you got a typo there

> button**L**ink !== button**l**ink

Remember javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: Great it helps, you can integrate linters to your code editor to help you find syntax mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing everything correctly expect you are not loading the video.
In function do something like

```
function changevid(buttonLink) {
video = document.getElementById('change');
video.src = buttonLink;
video.load(); //this line is imported to let browsesr fetch new video
}
```

Read the official w3 documentation with example on
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/load